# No Launcher activity found! in a widget

Tags: android, android-widget

Good evening.

I've seen that there are people with questions similar to this but I suppose mine is a little different since I haven't found a solution yet.

I've developed a basic widget that displays the battery percentage, and today, two people told me that they can't add my widget to their home screen because it doesn't appear neither in the widget list, neither in the installed applications list. They had to uninstall it from the Android Market.

I'm not sure if this is a bug on their AppWidgetPicker.apk or a bug in my Manifest since my widgets works in most devices. Feel free to search for "henrique rocha" in the Market and install my "Battery Widget" to see if you have the same problem.

In Eclipse I'm getting the following errors:
No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

I don't know if that might be the problem that causes the widget to not get listed in the widgets list.

Since I don't have an activity, neither a configuration activity and adding both action.MAIN and category.LAUNCHER to my intent-filter tag inside my receiver tag didn't solve the problem, I'm asking for your help.

Here is my full of Manifest if it helps.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/battery" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver android:name="BatteryAppWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <!-- Service to maintain widget alive -->
    <service android:name="BatteryService" />

</application>
```

And here is my appwidget_info.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="72dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
>
</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're right that since it is a widget you can't **launch** it from Eclipse: there is no Activity with the Launcher intent filter.

Include your entire Manifest so we can be sure you aren't leaving anything else out The AppWidget provider list should include any receivers that handle the AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE Intent, which yours does, BUT also has the [AppWidgetProviderInfo XML metadata](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData). If you have that it should work reliably on every handset that isn't somehow borked. I'd check if the folks reporting that it doesn't work are using alternative widget pickers.

Comment: Thanks. One of them is using Cyanogen 98 and I've asked him to replace his appwidgetpicker.apk to see if that's the problem. I've edited my question to include full manifest and widget's metadata xml.